# how to set session attribute in cq5

Tags: java, jsp, aem, sling

i am new to cq5, please help!! 
I am trying to set hashmap in session attribute. but for some reason i am getting JSP unable to compile.
Please help!!

```
   <%@include file="/apps/test/test2/global.jsp"%>
         <%@page session="false"
          import="org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap,
                  com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode,
                  com.day.cq.dam.scene7.api.net.NetUtils,
                  org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils,
                  javax.jcr.Session,
                  org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.UserManager,
                  org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user.Authorizable"  %>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


      <%
         Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
         Map<String, String> sessionValues = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          sessionValues.put("Id"+i, properties.get("test:Id"+i, "")); 
          sessionValues.put("Url"+i,properties.get("test:Url"+i,""));    
         }
       // put the hashmap as session    
         session.setAttribute("map", sessionValues);

         %>
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Session](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.6/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/jsr283/Session.html) you have is a repository session , which is very different from a HTTP [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). Javax.jcr.Session is your gateway to the content repository. It is not used to store session related attributes and does not have any setAttribute method. It is used to read and write to repository ( http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/how-jackrabbit-works.html ). If all your looking for is a http session , you should be getting it from [slingRequest](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html).

However if you use http sessions , you cannot cache pages in dispatcher ( https://forums.adobe.com/thread/960708 )

Comment: Hi sharath thank you for replying, as i am new to this env, Can you plz elaborate  on using sling request. Since i dont see any set method in this class. really appreciate your help!!

Comment: you should be doing slingRequest.getSession().setAttribute() . http sessions are generally not used. Pages are usually cached at the web server level , using sessions will hamper this.

Comment: okay, What about cookies in slingrequest? Can we do that in sling. I am sorry for being vague but please bare with me. Truly appreciate

Comment: you can use cookies, it's not that sling doesn't support http sessions. Page rendering is very resource intensive . So they are generally cached at a web server by a module called Dispatcher.  ( https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html ) . So requests don't come to CQ/AEM server every time. Removing caching will cause performance issues. So its always safer to use ajax or SSI for dynamic parts of the page. That would let you cache most of the page. Read : https://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/sling-dynamic-include/

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, you are using the wrong session. Beside this, they are different use cases and it depends on what are you trying to achieve. If you are trying to share a property between different components during the request life time, you can [set a servlet request attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
request.setAttribute(name, value)
```

This attribute will be reset when the request is finished.
If you want to persist the data in the user session, than can use the http session object available from the request:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(name, value)
```